# Separate apache sites with security in mind

Tags: php, apache, security, webserver

I have one machine running apache with php. It serves multiple domains from the folder /home/web/
Like /home/web/domainA and /home/web/domainB

Now, how do I securely separate them? Domain A must not be able to read, write or execute files in domain B's folder.

A virtual server is not a (well liked) option, since the server is low on RAM, and avoiding multiple boxes is preferable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.webtatic.com/packages/httpd-itk/ - could work for you. Assign different users to VirtualHosts and chown/chmod accordingly.

Comment: I might not use exactly this, but the article mentioned is useful too.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that apache user (or whatever user you configured to execute apache daemon) needs to read (and execute) every file for every domain you are serving, and since the apache daemon is the same for all domains, so are the file permissions.

So the only way you have for that IMHO are virtual boxes, to really isolate files and folders one from another.

Answer (score 0):

This page defines what I came for:

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RunningMultipleApacheInstances